# newbie PDO query display issue

Tags: php, pdo

newbie PDO question...

I think (hard to tell - buried in a wrapper class) I am doing a select query using:

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

wrapper:

```
return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

I am getting back just 1 record - like to display the results of just current customer....

My query is:

```
$results = $db->select("mytable", "id = 201"); //just 1 exact record)
```

then I can loop like:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
.... 
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $result["First"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result["Last"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result["id"]; ?></td>

</tr>
```

This all works fine, but since I only have 1 exact CUSTOMER record - I don't need to LOOP anything.

**My question is::** How do I display the columns without a loop?

The following failed:

```
echo $results["First"];
echo $results["First"][0];
echo $results["First"][1];
```

So what can I use to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `fetchAll`

```
$row = $pdostmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **`fetch`** function of PDO library.